# How to bind params in PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

I have a class, in that class, I have a method
like this:

```
  public function insert($fields){
    //$fields is the array containing key and values like this
    // $fields['name'=>'name_field','city'=>'city_field'];

    //INSERT INTO table_name (name,city) VALUES (':name',':city')

    $sql = "";
    $sql .= "INSERT INTO table_name (".implode(',', array_keys($fields)).") VALUES ";
    $sql .=  "(':".implode("',':", array_keys($fields)).")";


    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);


        //so here how can I bind parameters??


    $stmtExec = $stmt->execute();


}
```

Comment: You seem to know the right terms. Have you looked for methods with "bind" in the name in the [PDO section of the manual](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), or searched the web for "pdo bind params"?

Comment: Just pass the `$fields` as the argument of `$stmt->execute()`

Comment: @frz3993 after doing that it gives this error `Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/employee/classes/Employee.php:34 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/employee/classes/Employee.php(34): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/employee/create.php(16): Employee->insert(Array) #2 {main} thrown`

Comment: @Chris. yes, i have read and searched on the web for this but couldn't get the proper answer.

Comment: Your `implode()` should be something like `"(:".implode(", :", array_keys($array)).")";`

Comment: @RakeshKohali, it would be helpful if you included that information in your question. Specifically, what have you tried? In what way did it not work? [ask] has some good tips for asking questions effectively.

Comment: You can use a foreach to loop through your `fields` and do `bindValue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in a comment above, you should use a `foreach` loop to loop through your `fields` array and then `bindValue`.

This should work:

```
$fields = ['name'=>'name_field','city'=>'city_field'];

$implodeValue = implode(', ', array_keys($fields));
$implodeValuePlaceholder = implode(", :", array_keys($fields));

$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name ($implodeValue) VALUES (:".$implodeValuePlaceholder.")";
$stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);

foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
    echo $stmt->bindValue(':'.$key, $value);
}

$sql->execute();
```

Now This should work.

Comment: But it doesn't! Work that is!!

Comment: Try echoing `$sql` and see for yourself

Comment: @RiggsFolly I updated it. I believe it should work now. I forgot about `prepare` had a typo.

Comment: doing this it gives me following error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindValue() on string`

Comment: @Edward, i have found the problem. in your code it should be `$stmt->bindValue(':'.$key, $value);` . instead of `echo $sql->bindValue(':'.$key, $value);` And Thank you very much for the answer it solved my problem.

Comment: @RakeshKohali Sorry, `echo` was what I used to test to see if it was binding the right variables. Glad to help. :)